# How i can read custom field from object (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

How i can read `custom_fields` object from this response in **javascript** ?

```
 {
      "status": "ok",
      "post": {
        "id": 25,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "price-list",
        "url": "http://example.com/2016/02/10/post-title/",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "title",
        "title_plain": "title",
        "content": "",
        "excerpt": "",
        "date": "2016-02-10 12:23:40",
        "modified": "2016-06-01 06:27:39",
        "categories": [],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
          "id": 1,
          "slug": "slug",
          "name": "name",
          "first_name": "first name",
          "last_name": "last name",
          "nickname": "nickname",
          "url": "",
          "description": "descp"
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "custom_fields": {
          "Regular 95": [
            "34200:1"
          ],
          "Super 98": [
            "34900:0"
          ],
          "Gasoil": [
            "26100:-1"
          ],
          "Diesel": [
            "26200:1"
          ],
          "Kerosene": [
            "20100:-1"
          ],
          "Fuel / Ton": [
            "773.30:0"
          ]
        }
      },
      "previous_url": "http://example.com/2016/02/10/post-title/",
      "next_url": "http://example.com/2016/02/10/post-title/"
    }
```

Comment: `response.post.custom_fields`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `$.each`

```
$.each(response.post.custom_fields, function( index, value ) {
             console.log( index + ": " + value );
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var response={
      "status": "ok",
      "post": {
        "id": 25,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "price-list",
        "url": "http://example.com/2016/02/10/post-title/",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "title",
        "title_plain": "title",
        "content": "",
        "excerpt": "",
        "date": "2016-02-10 12:23:40",
        "modified": "2016-06-01 06:27:39",
        "categories": [],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
          "id": 1,
          "slug": "slug",
          "name": "name",
          "first_name": "first name",
          "last_name": "last name",
          "nickname": "nickname",
          "url": "",
          "description": "descp"
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "custom_fields": {
          "Regular 95": [
            "34200:1"
          ],
          "Super 98": [
            "34900:0"
          ],
          "Gasoil": [
            "26100:-1"
          ],
          "Diesel": [
            "26200:1"
          ],
          "Kerosene": [
            "20100:-1"
          ],
          "Fuel / Ton": [
            "773.30:0"
          ]
        }
      },
      "previous_url": "http://example.com/2016/02/10/post-title/",
      "next_url": "http://example.com/2016/02/10/post-title/"
    };
  
  $.each(response.post.custom_fields, function( index, value ) {
   console.log( index + ": " + value );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From w3c doc, diferents ways to accessing JavaScript Properties:

```
objectName.property          // person.age
objectName["property"]       // person["age"]
objectName[expression]       // x = "age"; person[x]
```

> The **expression** must evaluate to a property name.

You can use chaining with nested objects

```
objectName.internalObject.property
```